# Autowiring an interface having only one implementation - Unsatisfied bean dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have this controller in my Spring MVC web application,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spittles")
public class SpittleController {

    private SpittleRepository spittleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpittleController(SpittleRepository spittleRepository) {

        this.spittleRepository = spittleRepository;
    }

    public String spittles(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute(spittleRepository.findSpittles(Long.MAX_VALUE, 20));

        return "spittles";
    }

}
```

where SpittleRepository is an interface:

```
public interface SpittleRepository {

    List<Spittle> findSpittles(long max, int count);

}
```

where the implementation of SpittleRepository is as follows:

```
@Component
public class SpittleRepositoryImpl
    implements SpittleRepository {

    @Override
    public List<Spittle> findSpittles(long max, int count) {

        List<Spittle> spittles = new ArrayList<Spittle>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            spittles.add(new Spittle("Spittle" + i, new Date()));
        }
        return spittles;

    }

}
```

Even though I have autowired, I am getting:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'spittleController' defined in file
>   [C:\java\workspaces\default.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Chapter5-BuildingSpringWebApplications\WEB-INF\classes\org\spittr\web\SpittleController.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [org.spittr.data.SpittleRepository]: : No qualifying
>   bean of type [org.spittr.data.SpittleRepository] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.spittr.data.SpittleRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

where the java configuration file is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc                   // Enable Spring MVC
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"org.spittr"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
            new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer 
    configurer) {

        /* configure static content handling */
        configurer.enable();
    }



}
```

and project structure can be seen here:

[image]

RootConfig:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.spittr" }, 
               excludeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, 
                                          value = EnableWebMvc.class) })
public class RootConfig {

}
```

***SpittrWebAppInitializer.java***:

```
public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // Specify configuration class
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // Map DispatcherServlet to /
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Comment: Any chance that you have two interfaces named `SpittleRepository`  and the component implement some other interface with same name. Check the imports.

Comment: @Evgeni : Not at all.

Comment: Have You defined appropriate ComponentScanning within the class that defines non-web environment?Update Your post with the definition of the RootConfig class please.

Comment: Just for the purpose of testing try chaning from basePackages  to base Package Classes >> @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Spittle.class}, rest of code }

Comment: Plz add **SpittrWenAppInitializer.java** source code.

Comment: ohh sorry, forgot to mention-ur `Spring` version?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the package to be scanned-it is not properly defined, try chaning to :

```
main.java.org.spittr
```

or use the below method instead-I think it is much less error-prone.

```
basePackageClasses = {Spittle.class}
```

Regards,
Michał

Comment: I am out of the office. Will give it a try tomorrow, and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't know why ***Clean and Build*** solved the problem.